# PHP: Array sum by key wise

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple question but it seems complex to me. I have an array like the below. I wanna get output of 20,21,22,30,31,32 key's sum. Actually i Have tried as my own policy but wont get my desired result.

```
[P00000001] => Array
        (
            [20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 5.4
                    [2] => 8.9
                    [3] => 12                    
                ),
            [21] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 4.4
                    [2] => 3.9
                    [3] => 16                    
                ),
            [22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13
                    [1] => 5.4
                    [2] => 8.9
                    [3] => 12                    
                ),
        ),
        [P00000002] => Array
        (
            [30] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 5.4                    
                ),
            [31] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                    [1] => 4.4
                    [2] => 3.9                                    
                ),
            [32] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13
                    [1] => 5.4
                    [2] => 8.9
                    [3] => 12                    
                ),
        )
```

The output will be like the below. Hope guyz you got my point.

```
[P00000001] => Array
        (
            [20] => 38.3
            [21] => 36.3
            [22] => 39.3
            ),
        [P00000002] => Array
        (
            [30] => 17.4
            [31] => 20.3
            [32] => 39.3
        )
```

Comment: Iterate over the array and use `array_sum` to sum the values: https://3v4l.org/gmlF9

Comment: Thankz a lot..Its working Nick..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below snippet,

```
foreach($arr as $key => &$val){
    foreach($val as $k => $v)
    {
        $val[$k] = array_sum($v); // in second inner loop
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/heF6E).